# テキストファイル | head -n 500 | tail -n 1

Tags: bash

**先頭から500行読み込んだ後、2行目以降を表示する？**
・つまり、2行目から500行目まで表示するということでしょうか？

```
テキストファイル | head -n 500 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: 先頭から５００行読み込んだ後最後の一行を表示します。つまり５００行目を表示します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X`行目から`Y`行目まで表示するために、下記のコマンドはどうでしょうか。

```
head -n Y テキストファイル | tail -n Y-1
```

`2`行目から`500`行目までの場合は：

```
head -n 500 テキストファイル | tail -n 499
```